# unexpected switching between Headers frame and Data frame

Tags: netty

We are now developing a client-server system with Netty.
We sometimes find communication error.
Could you give me some advice if we might use Netty incorrectly.

We call writeHeadersFrame and writeDataFrame in this order in the following sendResponse.

But We sometimes find the unexpected switching between Headers frame and Data frame.

```
  private def sendResponse(
                            streamId: Int,
                            name: String,
                            status: ResponseStatus,
                            options: Map[String, String],
                            data: Option[PackableData],
                            isLast: Boolean): Unit =
    requestTable.get(streamId) match {
      case None =>
        log.error(s"sendResponse: streamId not found: $streamId")
      case Some(requestInfo) if requestInfo.ctx.channel.isActive =>
        writeResponseAccessLog(requestInfo.connectionTime, requestInfo.path, requestInfo.remoteAddress, status)
        writeHeadersFrame(requestInfo, streamId, status, isHeadersFrameEndStream(data, isLast))
        writeDataFrame(requestInfo, streamId, data, isLast)
        flush(requestInfo)
        removeStreamIdIfLast(streamId, isLast)
      case _ => detectedDisconnectionAndStop
    }


  private def writeHeadersFrame(requestInfo: RequestInfo, streamId: Int, status: ResponseStatus, isLast: Boolean): Unit = {
    log.debug(s"writeHeadersFrame($streamId, $status, $isLast)")
    val headers = new DefaultHttp2Headers().status(status.code.toString)
    headers.set(new AsciiString("content-type"), new AsciiString("application/x-msgpack"))

    val promise = requestInfo.ctx.newPromise()
    promise.addListener(new NettyChannelFutureListener(self))
    encoder.writeHeaders(requestInfo.ctx, streamId, headers, 0, isLast, promise)
  }




 private def writeBytesArray(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext, streamId: Int, bytes: Array[Byte], isLast: Boolean): Unit = {
    val byteBuffer = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(bytes)
    val promise: ChannelPromise = ctx.newPromise()
    promise.addListener(new NettyChannelFutureListener(self))
    log.debug(s"writeDataFrame: DATA Frame ${bytes.length} bytes, Readable bytes=${byteBuffer.readableBytes()}")
    encoder.writeData(ctx, streamId, byteBuffer, 0, isLast, promise)
  }

  private def writeDataFrame(requestInfo: RequestInfo, streamId: Int, data: Option[PackableData], isLast: Boolean): Unit = {
    log.debug(s"writeDataFrame: $streamId, $data, $isLast)")

    data match {
      case None =>
        log.info("writeDataFrame: No Data")
      case Some(packable) =>
        MessagePackUtil.serialize(packable) match {
          case Failure(e) =>
            log.error(s"writeDataFrame: serialize error: ${e.getMessage}")
          case Success(bytes: Array[Byte]) =>
            writeBytesArray(requestInfo.ctx, streamId, bytes, isLast)
        }
    }
  }
```